# Moq. Execute Action given as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, action, moq

How to mock the following method:

```
public class TimeService : ITimeService
{
    public void SetDelyEvent(int interval, bool reset,  Action action)
    {
        var timer = new Timer {Interval = interval, AutoReset = reset};
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => action();
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

I want to call the given ACTION.

```
var stub = new Mock<ITimeService>();
stub .Setup(m => m.SetDelyEvent(100, false, ACTION));
```

Comment: Are you wanting the Action passed in executed immediately as soon as the function call is performed just once, or are you trying to "re-create" the behavior of TimeService inside Moq?

Comment: I want to call the Action once immediately. This Action is a private method in my SUT. I have to call it in order to produce a result.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just use the `.Callback(` method to invoke a method that will be run when your mock executes, your callback function can be passed in the Action that was passed in to your original method, all you need to do is execute the Action in your callback.

```
    var stub = new Mock<ITimeService>();
    stub .Setup(m => m.SetDelyEvent(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<Action>()))
         .Callback((int interval, bool reset, Action action) => action());
```

Comment: Excellent. Only that ACTION must be `It.IsAny<Action>()`

Comment: Thats fine, it does not effect the solution, I only used `ACTION` because I thought it was a variable you declared. The code will work just as well doing `m.SetDelyEvent(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<Action>())`, you can still use the same callback.

Comment: @MiroslavPopov I have updated the code to use the any properties instead of the defined ones you used in your original example.

Comment: Works a treat for me too. Also worth noting that this works with dependency injected services, such as that of Autofac.